# Send an email notification to various addresses based on web-to-lead input answer

Tags: email, form

I've been searching all over for an answer to this. I want to know if it is possible to send an email to different recipients if a user answers a web-to-lead form question a certain way.

**Example:** I create a custom web-to-lead form field that is a select input of options. If a user selects option 1 and submits the form then andy@gmail.com gets notified via an email. If a user selects option 2 and submits, then bill@gmail.com gets notified via an email. In this scenario, both Andy and Bill are company employees, not end users.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Just notify them with an email.

Comment: Are the email address users or just specific emails?

Comment: Just specific email addresses. Our Salesforce account does not have enough licenses to cover all who would need to be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a [Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&type=5) for this. You can specify criteria for when it should fire (e.g. Lead Source equals Web and Custom Field equals Some Value), and then specify immediate actions like sending an email.

Answer (score 0):

yes Messanging.singleEmail class you can achieve this
Make sure your if condition is correct.. i just putted dummy only

```
 public class singleEmailExample{
 public PageReference sendingEmail(){
    if( contains(option1)){
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     String[] sendingTo = new String[]{‘andy@gmail.com’};
     semail.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
     semail.setSubject(‘Single Email message Example’);
     semail.setPlainTextBody(‘Hello!!!!!!!!!!This is a test email to test single email message program’);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {semail});

     return null;
    }

 if( contains(option2)){
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     String[] sendingTo = new String[]{‘bill@gmail.com’};
     semail.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
     semail.setSubject(‘Single Email message Example’);
     semail.setPlainTextBody(‘Hello!!!!!!!!!!This is a test email to test single email message program’);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {semail});

   return null;
    }
 }
```

Apex Page:

```
<apex:page controller="singleEmailExample">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:commandButton value="SendEmail" action="{!sendingEmail}"/>
 </apex:form>
```